# How do you add an account to Kadena Chainweaver?

Tags: pact-lang, kadena

When I was trying to deploy the HelloWorld contract using the [beginner tutorial](https://docs.kadena.io/learn-pact/beginner/hello-world), I got to the configuration page in the deployment popup. I made two public keys, but the tutorial specified nothing about the accounts. How do I create accounts so I can fill the account section?

[Deployment Configuration Page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po8Xm.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create accounts using the [testnet faucet](https://faucet.testnet.chainweb.com/). These are the steps:

1. On the page, click "Create and Fund new Account". You need to generate a public key on Chainweaver (which I assume you have already done if you were at the point of deployment) but if you haven't, then simply go to the menu on Chainweaver and click keys -> Generate Keys button.
2. Paste the public key on the faucet and give an account name. The account name can be anything you want, but making a k account is recommended. You can do this by going to the keys page on Chainweaver and clicking "Add k: Account", which should be right next to your public key.
3. The faucet should then give you a request key, which you need to copy. Then, go back to the accounts page on Chainweaver, where you should click "Check Tx Status".  Paste your request key in and click "Check Tx Status". It should say "Write succeeded", and you can click done.

If you refresh Chainweaver, you should see 20 KDA added to the account on a chain (typically chain 1). Hope that helps!